# MYSQL: Get substring from column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, varchar

I have the following `Varchar` data in a column in my `MYSQL` table:

```
Blank_Person_ID_776
Person_999
```

I want to extract the *final* number after the underscore to a variable (in this case 776) in order to use it in a query. I.e. ignore any underscore but the last one.

How can I do so?

I would like my final query to be as follows:

```
SET @personId= //query to get id;
Update Person set tracking_id = @personId where tracking_id is null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the final value after the last `'_'`, use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(<whatever>, '_', -1)
```

If you specifically want the final number in the string, even when there are characters after:

```
select regexp_replace(<whatever>, '.*_([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$', '$1')
```

Comment: Thanks for this Gordon, the issue with this is that there will be string with e.g. 3 underscores and some with 1. I have updated my questionto reflect this.

Comment: @java12399900 . . . That is not an issue for either of these approaches.  Both should work.

Comment: OK but what do I replace the "whatever" with to cover both cases?